# Mudando os templates de lugar (Django)

Tags: django, django-templates, static

Estava tentando deixar a pasta templates (principal) fora da pasta 'core' porque na verdade eu queria deixar a pasta 'templates' e 'static' fora da 'core'.

Vejam meu projeto no [GitHub](https://github.com/rg3915/semantic-template).

Dai eu tentei fazer o seguinte no settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'semantic', 'templates'), ],
        ...
    }

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'semantic', 'staticfiles'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'semantic', 'static')
```

Mas dessa forma ele carrega os templates, mas não carrega os 'static'.

O que eu faço?

Answer (score 0):

Execute o comando:

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```